# javascript: how to bind mouseover event in vue ref

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dom-events, ref

I would like to know how to **eliminate the mouseOver event from the template** by using `$ref`. I want to **control mouseOver behavior inside javascript instead**.

`Components` component has `myStats` child component. `myStats` is supposed to be displayed only when I hover over `Components`.

1. I am not sure how make `ref` do what the commented out template code does.
2. Do I have to use a function of `myStats` (= `onMouseEvent`)? It would be easier if I can control `mouseOver` only inside `Components`

`Components` code:

```
<template>
  <div class="pv-lookup" ref="myStats">
    <!-- I would like to get rid of the commented out mouse hover event code below by using $ref: -->
    <!-- <div @mouseover="mouseOver = true" @mouseout="mouseOver = false"> -->
    <div>
      <someComponent1 />
      <someComponent2 />
      <myStats v-if="mouseOver" @mouseMoved="onMouseMoved"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default class Components extends Vue {
  public mouseOver = false;

  @Emit()
  public onMouseMoved() {
    this.mouseOver = !this.mouseOver;
  }

  mounted() {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      if (this.isInhouseClient || this.isInhouse) {
        // TODO: set value for this.mouseOver

        // Approach 1:
        // ERROR: Property 'onMouseEvent' does not exist on type 'Vue | Element | Vue[] | Element[]'.
        this.$refs.myStats.onMouseEvent();

        // Approach 2:
        // ERROR: Property 'onMouseEvent' does not exist on type 'MouseEvent'. Did you mean 'initMouseEvent'?
        const myStats= this.$refs.myStatsas HTMLElement;
        myStats.addEventListener("mouseover", function( event ) {
          event.onMouseEvent();
        }, false);
        
        // Approach 3:
        // It's the simplest, but how do I connect with 'ref'?
        this.mouseOver = !this.mouseOver;
      }
    });
  }
}
</script>
```

`myStats` code:

```
<script>
export default class myStats extends Vue {
  public mouseOver: boolean = false;

  @Emit()
  public mouseMoved(){}
  
  public onMouseEvent() {
    this.mouseMoved();
  }
}
</script>
```

Thank you for your insights

Comment: Seems like XY Problem. Why event listeners in template are the problem?

Comment: I omitted many parts of the actual code. This component is irrelevant to many clients, so I don't want to always fire vue reactivity in that case. I want to control it in javascript for relevant clients only (if statement for this condition is omitted in this post for the sake of simplicity)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add event listeners for the same events (`mouseover` and `mouseout`) to the DOM element. Beware though, these events bubble up from children. In your case it would be better to use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`.

So your code will be:

```
  mounted() {
    const myStatsEl = this.$refs.myStats; // get DOM element of the component Components
    myStatsEl.addEventListener("mouseenter", (event) => {
      this.mouseOver = true;
    });

    myStatsEl.addEventListener("mouseleave", (event) => {
      this.mouseOver = false;
    });
  },
```

No need to emit events from myStats component or use its functions.

That being said, the correct 'Vue-way' of doing this would be with @mouseenter and @mouseleave, which is much cleaner. I'm not sure why you wouldn't want to use that. I can't think of any cases where this way might be limiting.